# Recover truncated file contents in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

I there any possibility to recover file contents after `echo "" > file.txt`?

I'm using **Ubuntu 10.04** and my filesystem is **[vzfs](http://forums.eukhost.com/f29/virtuozzo-file-system-vzfs-549/#.UQKFyGfzooc)**

Comment: What's behind your /dev/vzfs? Check with `mount`.

Comment: Do any other users have access to the same file?

Comment: @ott-- Mount produces following output:
`/dev/vzfs on / type vzfs (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)`

Comment: @JulianKnight Probably not cause i have edited the file.

Comment: My point was that, if another had the original file, your edit creates a local version of the shared file, that's how vzfs works. So they would have the original file and could let you have a copy back. But if you've edited it and then truncated, you are stuffed unless you also have a backup or version control.

Comment: @JulianKnight That's clear answer. You should post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If another had access to the original file, your edit creates a local version of the shared file, that's how vzfs works.

So they would have the original file and could let you have a copy back.

However, if you've edited it and then truncated, you are stuffed unless you also have a backup or version control.